# Series expansion of $\left(1 + x^2\right)^{-1/2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have the following function:
$$f(x) = arcsinh(x)$$
which i want to express as a series of powers. To do that I thought: 
$$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}$$
so 
$$f = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}dx= \int\left(1 - x^2\right)^{-1/2}dx$$
and now i will expand that using the binomial expansion $(1 + x)^a$. I tried several ways to make that expansion but I couls not get a compact expression. After some search I saw that:
$$\left(1 - x\right)^{-1/2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k(2k)!}{2^{2k}(k!)^2}x^k$$
But I dont understand how this expression was obtained.Any other ideas for expressing my function as a series of powers or a demonsstration as to how this expression is obtined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(1+x^2)^{-1/ 2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{-1/ 2}{n} x^{2n}$$

\begin{align}
\binom{-1/ 2}{n}
&= \frac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(-\tfrac12-k)}{n!}
= \frac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\big[\tfrac12(-1)(2k+1)\big]}{n!}\\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^nn!} \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k+1)\\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^nn!} \frac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\big[(2k+1)(2k+2)\big]}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\big[2(k+1)\big]}\\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^nn!} \frac{\prod_{k=0}^{2n-1}(k+1)}{2^n\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+1)}
= \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2^nn!} \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}\\
&= \frac{(-1)^n (2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^2}
%
\end{align}

then (fixing your sign mistake), where the power series about $0$ for $\arcsin(x)$ is defined,

$$\arcsin(x) = \int \frac{dx}{(1-x^2)^{1/ 2}}
= \int\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{-1/ 2}{n} (-x^2)^{n}
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \binom{-1/ 2}{n}x^{2n+1}$$
and you can do the rest...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it.

Comment: I think that I have entered this exact sequence at least twice.

Comment: @martycohen As have I, but always as a lemma to an answer. For the life of me I've never managed to actually memorize it and always end up rederiving it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=u(x)=1+x^2$.
For $k\ge0$, making use of the Faa di Bruno formula and some properties of the partial Bell polynomials $B_{n,k}$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\biggl[\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}\biggr]^{(k)}&=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{\textrm{d}^j}{\textrm{d} u^j}\biggl(\frac{1}{u^{1/2}}\biggr) B_{k,j}(2x,2,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{\langle-1/2\rangle_j}{u^{1/2+j}} 2^jB_{k,j}(x,1,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{\langle-1/2\rangle_j}{(1+x^2)^{1/2+j}} 2^j \frac{1}{2^{k-j}}\frac{k!}{j!}\binom{j}{k-j}x^{2j-k}\\
&=\frac{k!}{2^k(1+x^2)^{1/2}} \sum_{j=0}^{k}\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_j\frac{2^{2j}}{j!}\binom{j}{k-j}\frac{x^{2j-k}}{(1+x^2)^{j}}\\
&\to\begin{cases}\displaystyle \frac{(2m)!}{2^{2m}}\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_m\frac{2^{2m}}{m!}\binom{m}{2m-m}, & \text{$k=2m$ is even}\\
0,& \text{$k$ is odd}
\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases}\displaystyle (-1)^m\frac{(2m)!(2m-1)!!}{(2m)!!}, & \text{$k=2m$ is even}\\
0,& \text{$k$ is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
as $x\to0$. Consequently, we acquire
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty(-1)^m\frac{(2m-1)!!}{(2m)!!}x^{2m}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{arcsinh}x=\sum_{m=0}^\infty(-1)^m\frac{(2m-1)!!}{(2m)!!}\frac{x^{2m+1}}{2m+1}.
\end{equation}

References

1. Siqintuya Jin, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, *Partial Bell polynomials, falling and rising factorials, Stirling numbers, and combinatorial identities*, Computer Modeling in Engineering & Sciences **132** (2022), no. 3, 781--799; available online at https://doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2022.019941.
2. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterr. J. Math. **14** (2017), no. 3, Article 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.
3. F. Qi, D.-W. Niu, D. Lim, and Y.-H. Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, J. Math. Anal. Appl. **491** (2020), no. 2, Article 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.